# Precision in bar chart of chartjs

Tags: chart.js

I use a bar chart from chart.js as shown below

[bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoiBd.png)

Now I would like to show 4 decimals instead of 3, but I can only find how to do this for line charts.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

All values are formatted to 3 decimals by default in Chart.js and there doesn't seem to be a setting that allows you to change the number of decimals directly.

Instead, you can use the raw value and format it yourself by overriding the label callback in the chart options:

```
.
.
.
plugins: {
  tooltip: {
    callbacks: {
      label: function(context) {
        return Number((context.raw || 0)).toFixed(4);
      }
    }
  }
}
.
.
.
```

Edit: Added a working example to demonstrate 4 decimals showing in a bar chart:
https://jsfiddle.net/j2Lwbmu8/

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me, for now I modified formatNumber
function formatNumber(num, locale, options) {
  //return getNumberFormat(locale, options).format(num);
    return num;
}

Comment: @bartje either you are using an older version of Chart.js which works differently or else you aren't putting the plugin code into the chart option correctly. I updated my answer with a working example to hopefully make this more clear.